# Run exectuble in background and wait for its end (shell script)

Tags: python, shell

I am new to shell script and what I want to do is, I need to run 4 instances of my executable and then wait for them to end to run my final script right now what I have is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ -std=c++110x BC-Boost.cpp -o bc-boost   
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
python initialization.py -c $i
./bc-boost $i
done
python ploting.py
```

The problem is; right now my script run `initialization.py, ./bc-boost` sequentially I want to run them into background and somehow tell `ploting.py` to be run when all the above codes are done! (and I don't want to go to threading and ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go for something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ -std=c++110x BC-Boost.cpp -o bc-boost   
for i in 1 2 3 4 ; do
    ( python initialization.py -c $i ; ./bc-boost $i ) &
done
for i in 1 2 3 4 ; do
    wait
done    
python ploting.py
```

This can be seen with the following test program:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 2 3 4 ; do
    (
        echo "$i start $(date)"
        sleep $i
        sleep $i
        echo "$i   end $(date)"
    ) &
done
for i in 1 2 3 4 ; do
    wait
done
echo all done
```

which outputs:

```
1 start Thu, Mar 26, 2015 11:21:00 AM
2 start Thu, Mar 26, 2015 11:21:00 AM
3 start Thu, Mar 26, 2015 11:21:00 AM
4 start Thu, Mar 26, 2015 11:21:00 AM
1   end Thu, Mar 26, 2015 11:21:02 AM
2   end Thu, Mar 26, 2015 11:21:04 AM
3   end Thu, Mar 26, 2015 11:21:06 AM
4   end Thu, Mar 26, 2015 11:21:08 AM
all done
```

Comment: @Am1rr3zA, "not working" is not really the most _helpful_ bug report :-) Perhaps you could elaborate on what it's doing wrong. As per the test payload I posted, the code successfully starts four tasks in parallel then waits for all four to finish before continuing.

Comment: I agree with you the problem is I don't know how can  explain the error, actually my shell script is a little bit different (each executable has more input argument) yet I am not sure that cause any problem. and my C write some log file in console when used your solution the initialization part worked fine yet the C executable encountered an error and just working fine for the last index (i = 4)

Comment: @Am1rr3zA, provided the payload is correct within the `( ... )` bit, they should run fine in parallel. The fact that the C program, `bc-boost` I assume, only works for the final loop tends to suggest it can't run in parallel. For example, it each instance opens and writes to the same file. It's unlikely to be a problem with the parallelisation itself since that works okay with a basic payload. Perhaps you might ask another question on whether the code in that program would run into trouble if multiple copies ran side by side.

Comment: Thanks based on your answer I have some ideas, I will check them and if it works I will come back here and accept this answer